# Error: Cannot resolve module 'style-loader'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm using style-loader with webpack and react framework. When I run webpack in terminal i'm getting `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'style-loader'` in import.js file although i've specified the file path correctly.

```
import '../css/style.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import TopicsList from '../components/topic-list.jsx';
import Layout from '../components/layout.jsx';
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
      // Set up an ES6-ish environment
      'babel-polyfill',

      // Add your application's scripts below
      APP_DIR + '/import.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel',

                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
                }
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Try run script below:

`npm install style-loader --save`

Modify webpack config, add `modulesDirectories` field in `resolve`.

```
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
        modulesDirectories: [
          'node_modules'
        ]        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I had previously installed `npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev` but for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: Could you upload your webpack config file?

Comment: Answer updated, just need add `modulesDirectories ` in `resolve`.

Comment: worked for me, however had to install uri-loader and file-loader modules too

Comment: This reply helps me when trying to run react with webpack

Comment: This add to where?

Comment: Error: '... configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'modulesDirectories'' with webpack 5.89.0

To solve I have replaced moduleDirectories with 
modules: [
            'node_modules'
          ]

Answer (score 32):

Please run this script:

```
 npm install style-loader css-loader --save
```

Set your module as below:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: path.join(_dirname, 'app')
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
    }
  ],
  resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  }
}
```

It's basically reading as for loaders - test jsx using babel-loader and the next test is a css file using style-loader and css-loader, which will recognize the modules. Also, you should exit out of npm start, and run "npm install" and run "npm start". Hopefully, this should take care of the issue.

Answer (score 22):

If you try to import a css file with this line:

```
import '../css/style.css';
```

and have added the `style-loader` in your webpack config.

The error states:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'style-loader'

the *module* named "style-loader" is not resolved.

You need to install that module with:

```
$ npm install style-loader --save-dev
```

Or, if you're using yarn:

```
$ yarn add style-loader -D
```

Then run `webpack` again.

Comment: --save-dev please!

Answer (score 14):

I wanted to add on to what [David Guan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5076405/david-guan) said. In the newer versions of Webpack (V2+) `moduleDirectories` has been replaced with `modules`. The updated `resolve` portion of his answer would look like this:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'], //An empty string is no longer required.
    modules: [
      'node_modules'
    ]        
}
```

For more information you can check out their [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve). Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Official Documentation link is broken (404)

Answer (score 11):

Under Webpack 3, with `node_module` in a non-standard location, I had to use both `resolve` and [`resolveLoader`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#resolving-loaders) configuration objects:

```
resolve: {
  modules: ["build-resource/js/node_modules"]
},
resolveLoader: {
  modules: ["build-resource/js/node_modules"]
},
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed for me too. I'm embedding webpack into a CLI that is run from other folders, and so it couldn't find my loaders. Setting modules to `__dirname + 'node_modules'` worked!

Answer (score 2):

I use Windows and did everything but nothing worked. It appeared console didn't have enough permissions. So, after running in Admin mode I re-entered

```
npm install
```

and everything worked. You can see the result by appearing a lot of modules in node_modules directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you're node_modules are on the same dir as your webpack config file you can simply add `context: __dirname`.

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: [
    ...
```

(works in both **webpack 1 and 2**)

Answer (score 0):

remove 'style-loader!css-loader', make it ['style-loader','css-loader']
remove empty string '' from extensions array. It will be look like bellow

```
module:{
        rules:[
            {test:/\.css$/,use:['style-loader','css-loader']},
            
        ]
    },
    
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],   
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to your dependencies

**npm i style-loader css-loader**

Answer (score -2):

it is very simple you have to install the fist syle-loader the css-loader.

Comment: It is better to include the essential steps to install the missing module.